# Error in regression loop

Tags: matlab, loops, regression

the following matlab code is a regression loop:

```
for j=1:size(X,2)
IdentityVector=ones((size(t,1)-1),1);
Y=X((2:end),j);
if j==1 
X2=[IdentityVector,X((2:end),((j+1):end)),Diff1X];
elseif j>1 & j<size(X,2)
X2=[IdentityVector,X((2:end),(1:(j-1))),X((2:end),((j+1):end)),Diff1X];
elseif j==size(X,2)
X2=[IdentityVector,X((2:end),(1:(j-1))),Diff1X];
end
[b(:,j)]= regress(Y,X2);
end
```

this works fine for the beta estimate as it for each j the dimensions of the beta are adjusting accordingly, although if I request from the estimation some additional features/statistics e.g. `[b,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(y,X)` the adjustments i have tried for each j do not work. Any help?

Comment: Can you define "does not work"?

Comment: Yeah as Matt said i tried to treat `bint` as a vector which is not. It is a T*2 matrix for each j which means that in the end I should have a T*12 matrix. Seems like with cells is more simple so I'll stick to that. Of course any other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you are treating all the outputs as vectors, which they are not.  If you read `doc regress` you will see that `bint` is a p-by-2, `r` is n-by-2, so on and so forth.  That means you can't assign `bint(:,j)` because `bint` itself is a matrix.  Instead try cells.

```
[b{j}, bint{j}, r{j}, rint{j}, stats{j}]= regress(Y,X2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt! That was helpful! :)